# Check My Python Code to Combine 2 Lists and Print to File

Tags: python, list, printing

I was wondering if you could help me by telling me what I got wrong in this code that I've got. I'm trying to combine two lists together to run through my contact form poster to try to get leads. My developer did this code for me. I'm just too dumb. :)

Here is what I've got so far:

```
for city in cities:
    for company_type in company_types:
        file = open("list.txt", "w")
        file.write(company_type.strip() + " in " + city.strip() + "\n")
        file.close()
```

I would really appreciate the help!

Comment: What specific problem are you having with your code? Is it an error? Or the fact your file only contains one item?

Comment: What two list? Combine them how?

Answer (score 3):

```
with open("list.txt", "w") as f:
    for city in cities:
        for company_type in company_types:
            f.write(company_type.strip() + " in " + city.strip() + "\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are Issues as far as I can tell

- The file variable is overwritten on each iteration of the inner loop, so it will only contain the last combination of city and company type.
- The file is opened in write mode ("w") on each iteration of the inner loop, which means that the file will be overwritten on each iteration. This means that the file will only contain the last combination of city and company type.

To fix these, you can do the following.

- Initialize an empty list called combinations before the loops.
- Inside the loops, append the combination of city and company type to the combinations list.
- After the loops, open the file in append mode ("a") and write all of the combinations in the combinations list to the file.

here is sample code you can use

```
combinations = []
for city in cities:
    for company_type in company_types:
        combination = company_type.strip() + " in " + city.strip()
        combinations.append(combination)

file = open("list.txt", "a")
for combination in combinations:
    file.write(combination + "\n")
file.close()
```

I hope this would help!